# How can I batch move a prepended year to the end of a file name?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, rename

I have a list of files (thousands of them) like this:

```
/path/2010 - filename.txt
/path/2011 - another file name.txt
```

Always following this pattern: `#### - string.txt`

I need to change them to look like this:

```
/path/filename (2010).txt
/path/another file name (2011).txt
```

How can I do this quickly with bash, shell, terminal, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested.

```
find /path -name '???? - *.txt' -print0 | while read -d ''; do
    [[ $REPLY =~ (.*)/(....)\ -\ (.*)\.txt$ ]] || continue

    path=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    year=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    str=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    echo mv "$REPLY" "$path/$str ($year).txt"
done
```

Remove the `echo` once the generated `mv` commands look right.

Comment: How can I add slashes to escape the spaces in the path and file names?

Comment: (.*) should greedily match everything up to the final slash, spaces and all. '\ ' is escaping the spaces in the file name proper. I don't think there should be any other issues with spaces.

Comment: Doh, unescaped spaces only showed up in echo.  Mv worked just fine.  Thanks.  Giving you the "answer" because it worked without another library.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Try [`rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html) command:

```
rename -n 's/(.*) - (.*)(\.txt)/$2 ($1)$3/' *.txt
```

---

`-n`(--no-act) option is for preview.
Remove `-n` to perform substitution.

Comment: Shoot, my Mac doesn't have rename (`-bash: rename: command not found`).  Can I do this with `mv`?

Comment: If `*.txt` expands to too many files for one command line, `find /path -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 rename -n ...`

Comment: `rename` is a tiny perl script. I think you can install it in MAC.

Comment: Love rename, especially the `-n` part

Answer (score 2):

I know you didn't tag it with `zsh` but you did say `shell`. Anyway here's how to do it with the `zmv` function in `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv                      # It's not loaded by default
zmv -nvw '* - *.*' '$2 ($1).$3'
```

Remove `-n` when you're happy with the output.

`-v` makes `zmv` verbose. `-w` implicitly makes a group of each wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to add this as a comment, but I'm not yet allowed to.

I asked a similar question and received a number of helpful answers over here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37355/recursively-rename-subdirectories-that-match-a-regex

Perhaps one of those solutions can be adapted to suit you needs.