# linux shell script to remove digits

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to rename 200 files
Actually each files is named liked this :

```
00001-abcd-efgg?g.............
00002-xcvb-vbnv?b.............
00003-cbvc-hugh?j.............
```

Now I want to rename all this files like this :

```
001
002
003
...
```

So I need to remove the first 2 digit, and to remove also everything after the fifth digit.
Warning : there's a " ? " in each file I want to rename.

Comment: That's nice... have you tried this at all yourself, or are you just wanting us to do your job for you?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990893/how-can-i-batch-move-a-prepended-year-to-the-end-of-a-file-name/11991049#11991049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rename`:

```
rename -nv 's,.*(\d{3}).*,$1,' *
```

Output:

```
00001-abcd-efgg?g............. renamed as 001
00002-xcvb-vbnv?b............. renamed as 002
00003-cbvc-hugh?j............. renamed as 003
```

Remove the `n` when you're satisfied with the output.

Answer (score 4):

```
for f in *
do
   mv "$f" "${f:2:3}"
done
```