# Renaming files with Bash, removing prefix and suffix

Tags: bash, shell, file-rename

I want to rename a bunch of files using bash, transforming this file pattern:

```
prefix - name - suffix.txt
```

Into this one:

```
name.txt
```

For that I wrote the following script:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | while read f
do
  mv "${f}" "${f/prefix - /}"
done

find . -name "*.txt" | while read f
do
  mv "${f}" "${f/ - suffix/}"
done
```

It works, but I'd like to perform the renaming using a single loop. Is it possible?

Comment: If you have `rename` installed, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990893/how-can-i-batch-move-a-prepended-year-to-the-end-of-a-file-name/11991049#11991049

Comment: I'm in a Mac, I don't have `rename` installed by default

Comment: I'm using OSX and I have rename avaliable to me. Are you sure it isn't there?

Comment: @beth yep, still not available in my OSX. It must have been added on a later version (I'm using 10.8.5), or perhaps you installed it at some point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another approach, for fun, using regular expressions:

```
regex='prefix - (.*) - suffix.txt'
for f in *.txt; do
    [[ $f =~ $regex ]] && mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.txt"
done
```

---

Actually, using the simple pattern '*.txt' here has two problems:

1. It's too broad; you may need to apply the regex to a lot of non-matching files.
2. If there are a *lot* of files in the current directory, the command line could overflow.

Using `find` complicates the procedure, but is more correct:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex 'prefix - .* - suffix.txt' -print0 | \
  while read -d '' -r; do
   [[ $REPLY =~ $regex ]] && mv "$REPLY" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.txt"
  done
```

Comment: I like this answer. Just a comment: for the last part to work, it must be written as `"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.txt"`. Please fix it and I'll accept this answer

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to `GNU sed`, you could use some regex to perform something like:

```
for i in *.txt; do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed -r 's/([^-]*)\s-\s(.*)\s-\s([^-]*)\.txt/\2.txt/')"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use this:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | awk -v RS="\0" -v ORS="\0" '{print $0;sub(/^prefix - /,""); sub(/ - suffix.txt$/,".txt"); print $0; }' | xargs -0 -n 2 mv
```

which could be written more clearly as:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 |
awk -v RS="\0" -v ORS="\0" '{
  print $0;
  sub(/^prefix - /,""); 
  sub(/ - suffix.txt$/,".txt"); 
  print $0;
}' |
xargs -0 -n 2 mv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `emacs` installed. You can use the `dired` feature.

### In `bash`:

```
# open your dir with emacs
emacs /path/to/your/dir
```

### In `emacs`:

- Press <kbd>*</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>**`\.txt$`**<kbd>Enter</kbd> to mark all `txt` files.
- Press <kbd>%</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>**`.*- \(.*\) -.*`**<kbd>Enter</kbd>**`\1.txt`**<kbd>Enter</kbd> to rename.